# Wordpress - When selecting categories, how can I display only posts from within this month?

Tags: wordpress, post, limit, categories

Our website is a monthly publication and we want to keep the older posts, however we do not want the users to see last months posts when the click on a section from the navigation.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Combining_Parameters) for this from WordPress Codex article:

> Posts for category 13, for the current month on the main page:

```
if ( is_home() ) {
    query_posts( $query_string . '&cat=13&monthnum=' . date( 'n', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );
}
```